# I want remove/hide HttpResponse header in Struts 1.0

Tags: java, servlets, web, weblogic12c, hacklang

I have tried below  in web.xml but no working

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

I want to do it at application level, How I can do it Programmatically or in configuration file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by doing setting in Weblogic console

1. Go To weblogic Console
2. Go to Domain
3. Go to web Application
4. Select X-Powerred-By- Header values as : " X-Powerred-By- Header will not be sent "
5. Save changes